# Why did Mathematica choose brackets for function arguments over parentheses?

Tags: symbols, language-design

This is a non-technical question. I'm just curious why *Mathematica* breaks the convention that parentheses are widely used for function arguments. What's the advantage of `f[x]` over `f(x)`?

Again, for the derivative of a function, `f'(x)` and `f''(x)` are more familiar than `f'[x]` and `f''[x]`. I think these conventions in math textbooks have already existed for hundreds of years.

If function arguments are denoted as `f(x)`, then `array[i]` could be used as array index. (c.f. *Mathematica* uses `array[[i]]` here.)

To quote from the official documentation:

> **The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language**
>
> `(term)` parentheses for grouping
>
> `f[x]` square brackets for functions
>
> `{a, b, c}`    curly braces for lists
>
> `v[[i]]`   double brackets for indexing (`Part[v, i]`)

Are there any historical or antithetical reasons for choosing these notations?

Comment: "If function arguments are denotes as f(x), then array[i] could be used as array index.(c.f. Mathematica uses [[i]] here.)" — is `(f + g)(x + y)` parenthesizing and multiplying two terms or is it a function call (like `(f + g)[x + y]` in the current syntax)?

Comment: @rm-rf Your example is quite straight forward. Thank you! BTW. Your user name `rm -rf` is a dangerous yet powerful command. I miss it on Windows.

Comment: @rm-rf A few days ago I did a `rm *` accidentally (I meant `rm *.pdf`) and lost about 15GB of stuff :)

Comment: A choice of ruling out ambiguity.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. Most people want to multiply numbers without having to use the `*` symbol, e.g. `3x` vs `3*x`.

So given that this exists in Mathematica, using `()` for function arguments would introduce ambiguity.

Is `f(x + y)` meant to be `f[x + y]` or `f*(x + y)`?

This is actually a problem Wolfram|Alpha faces since it allows for all forms of inputs.

Other languages like C chose the other route, which means you *must* use `*` to indicate multiplication. Given that Mathematica's original purpose was for mathematics, I think the right choice was made.

Comment: Though simple, good to know for the new commers. Thank you.

Comment: +1 This very example is discussed in [The Mathematica Book](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v2/contents/1.1.6.pdf).

Answer (score 14):

Although Chip's answer already suffices to address the question, I would like to quote here a relevant part of the dialog by Theo Gray and Jerry Glynn in their book *[Exploring Mathematics with Mathematica](http://books.google.com/books?id=p0JzmwEACAAJ)*; as there does not seem to be an easily accessible online version or preview of the book anywhere, I hope the quotation is useful:

> …
>
> **Theo:** Satisfied?  *Mathematica* also knows about a whole bunch of other functions, such as trigonometric functions.  One of the weird
>   things about *Mathematica* that tends to annoy people for a while is
>   that you have to use square brackets and capital letters.  For
>   example:
>
> ```
> Sin[1.2]
>    0.932039
> ```
>
> **Jerry:** In other words, you're saying I can't type `sin 1.2` with no parentheses, or `sin(1.2)`, or `Sin(1.2)`, or `sin[1.2]`.  I must
>   type `Sin[1.2]`, exactly as you did.  That seems like a real
>   imposition.
>
> **Theo:** Yes, you have to type `Sin[1.2]`, exactly.  There are good reasons for both requirements, and we'll see why in later chapters. 
>   If you use one of the variations you suggested above, *Mathematica*
>   will warn you that you are probably making a mistake.  All of your
>   variations are legal *Mathematica* input, but they don't mean what you
>   want.  (For example, `sin(1.2)` means the variable named `sin`
>   multiplied by `1.2`.)
>
> **Jerry:** OK, I'll live with the funny brackets for now.
>
> …
>
> **Jerry:** …now, what about square brackets?  Why can't I use `Sin(x)` instead of `Sin[x]`?
>
> **Theo:** Good question!  There is, in fact, a good reason.  Ordinary mathematical notation is inconsistent here.  Round parentheses are
>   used to mean two completely different things in traditional notation:
>   first, order of evaluation; second, function arguments.  Consider the
>   expression `k(b + c)`.  Does this mean `k` times the quantity `b + c`,
>   or does it mean the function `k` with the argument `b + c`?  Unless
>   you know from somewhere else that `k` is a function, or that `k` is a
>   variable, you can't tell.  It's a mistake to use the same symbols to
>   mean these two completely different things, and *Mathematica* corrects
>   this mistake by using round parentheses only for order of evaluation,
>   and square brackets only for function arguments.
>
> **Jerry:** That's a nice point.  I never thought of that before.  It shows how easily we adapt to nonsense.  Aside from that, are you
>   saying that mathematicians have been sloppy for centuries?  That's a
>   pretty strong statement!
>
> **Theo:** Yes.  Although I'm all in favor of interesting, quirky languages for writing novels and poetry (English comes to mind), it's
>   really a bad idea to use an ambiguous language for something like
>   mathematics.  One of the great contributions of computer science to
>   the world has been a powerful set of tools for thinking about what
>   makes a language "good".
>
> An alternative would  be to insist on using a `*` for all
>   multiplication. Then `k(b + c)` would always mean the function `k`,
>   and if you wanted it to mean multiplication you would have to use
>   `k*(b + c)`.  We decided it was better to remove an inconsistency than
>   to force people to use an extra symbol.  Another option would have
>   been to have *Mathematica* "know" what was a variable and what was a
>   function.  This turns out to have serious consequences, and it's
>   really not a good idea.
>
> **Jerry:** Well, I didn't expect a lecture!
>
> **Theo:** Sorry.  Let's get back to the matter at hand.  For functions, you use square brackets.  Let's use the `Sin` function
>   together with some round parentheses, to see how they fit:
>
> ```
> Sin[1.2 (3 + 4)] (4 + 5)
>    7.69139
> ```
>
> **Jerry:** This means, Find the sine of 1.2 times 7 and multiply that answer by 9.
>
> **Theo:** Yes.
>
> …

Comment: "Another option would have been to have Mathematica "know" what was a variable and what was a function. This turns out to have serious consequences, and it's really not a good idea."
Can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: @daniatic In `countPos[list_, a_, k_] := Total@Table[Boole[Positive[k(x - a)]], {x, list}]`, is `k` a function or a scalar? It depends on what I, the user, have in mind, which cannot be determined from the code.

Comment: "If you use one of the variations you suggested above, Mathematica will warn you that you are probably making a mistake."  -- not sure about that (see some of the questions that arise here every day)

Comment: @Chris, I haven't looked at 2.2 (the version they were using when that book was written) in a long while to prove or disprove that, but I do agree we still get a lot of those basic syntax questions every so often... o well.