# Create a list of all functions given a set of arguments

Tags: function-construction, combinatorics

I'm trying to examine some patterns on the permutation of elements in finite element functions. I'd like to create a list of all functions (`256` of them) on `4` elements.

For example

```
{{(a, b), (b, c), (c, c), (d, a)}, {(a, c), (b, d), (c, c), (d, a)}, ... }
```

In all the methods I have tried I keep getting non-functional elements, i.e.
things like

```
{{(a, b), (a, c), (c, d), (d, a)}, ... }
```

Any suggestions as for an easy way to do this?

Comment: You might want to look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72976/why-mathematica-chooses-bracket-for-function-arguments-over-parenthesis)

Comment: What method have you tried such that you're getting 'non-functional' elements?

Comment: Your "code" is not *Mathematica*-compatible. Would you mind fixing the round brackets?

Comment: Also, let me check that I understand you correctly: you're trying to generate all mappings from the set `{a, b, c, d}` onto itself?

Comment: @2012rcampion yes, exactly: your answer below was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
set = {a, b, c, d};
maps = Thread[set -> #] & /@ Tuples[set, {Length[set]}]
```

If you want all permutations (one-to-one mappings from `set` onto `set`) replace `Tuples` with `Permutations[set]`.

Comment: This is great. And indeed, I was not looking for just 1-1 mappings. Thanks so much.  Much better than other options using nests of combinations etc. Thanks again.